# angular5 project fails to create

Tags: windows, npm, proxy, angular5

I have successfully installed node and angular5 by providing credential to bypass proxy server as i am located under a us govt network proxy. 
but when i try to create a new angular project, i get this following error from the log, i am local admin on my machine, please assist. 
Thanks
Yogi

please find the error log appended below

```
29741 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json.3554057648' -> 'C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json'
29742 verbose cwd C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload
29743 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
29744 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
29745 verbose node v8.9.4
29746 verbose npm  v5.6.0
29747 error path C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json.3554057648
29748 error code EPERM
29749 error errno -4048
29750 error syscall rename
29751 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json.3554057648' -> 'C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json'
29751 error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json.3554057648' -> 'C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json'
29751 error   cause:
29751 error    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json.3554057648' -> 'C:\TFS_Y\Angular\SidUpload\node_modules\killable\package.json'
29751 error      errno: -4048,
29751 error      code: 'EPERM',
29751 error      syscall: 'rename',
29751 error      path: 'C:\\TFS_Y\\Angular\\SidUpload\\node_modules\\killable\\package.json.3554057648',
29751 error      dest: 'C:\\TFS_Y\\Angular\\SidUpload\\node_modules\\killable\\package.json' },
29751 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename \'C:\\TFS_Y\\Angular\\SidUpload\\node_modules\\killable\\package.json.3554057648\' -> \'C:\\TFS_Y\\Angular\\SidUpload\\node_modules\\killable\\package.json\'',
29751 error   errno: -4048,
29751 error   code: 'EPERM',
29751 error   syscall: 'rename',
29751 error   path: 'C:\\TFS_Y\\Angular\\SidUpload\\node_modules\\killable\\package.json.3554057648',
29751 error   dest: 'C:\\TFS_Y\\Angular\\SidUpload\\node_modules\\killable\\package.json',
29751 error   parent: 'sid-upload' }
29752 error **Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.**
29753 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

Comment: Did you try `npm cache clean` ? refer this GitHub issue for more details - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/696

Comment: yes I did clean up npm cache -f multiple times